# linux, error building AM33 Yocto image, bitbake

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I am following the steps here:http://variwiki.com/index.php?title=VAR-SOM-AM33_Yocto_FIDO_GS

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/philip/yocto_varsomam33/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-linux-gnueabi/input-utils/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.3467)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/philip/yocto_varsomam33/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-linux-gnueabi/input-utils/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.3467
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 6 DESTDIR=/home/philip/yocto_varsomam33/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-linux-gnueabi/input-utils/1.0-r0/image STRIP=
| Make.config:1: *** empty variable name.  Stop.
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/philip/yocto_varsomam33/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-linux-gnueabi/input-utils/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.3467)
ERROR: Task 1815 (/home/philip/yocto_varsomam33/tisdk/sources/meta-arago/meta-arago-extras/recipes-devtools/input-utils/input-utils_1.0.bb, do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3217 tasks of which 3211 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory
Waiting for 0 running tasks to finish:

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/philip/yocto_varsomam33/tisdk/sources/meta-arago/meta-arago-extras/recipes-devtools/input-utils/input-utils_1.0.bb, do_compile
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

If I look at the inputs-utils_1.0.bb file:

```
# set the DESTDIR and the STRIP variables used by the GNUmakefile.
# The STRIP variable is set to blank or else the variable setting from OE
# is picked up as <TC>-strip and the install step sees that as another
# file to install.
EXTRA_OEMAKE = "DESTDIR=${D} STRIP=''"

do_install () {
    oe_runmake install
}
```

What to I do with the STRIP variable?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt the VM with ubuntu 14.04 and now it works